# mod_rewrite isn't rewriting properly. Some rules work. Others return 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, rule

I've put about 15 mod_rewrite rules in .htaccess to send traffic from some old pages to the homepage. They all look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^contact_us.php$ index.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^cookie_usage.php$ index.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^articles.php$ index.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^affiliate.php$ index.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^advanced_search.php$ index.php [R=301,L]
```

All of them properly redirect to index.php ***except*** affiliate.php. It returns a 404 Not Found. There are no other rules that have a word remotely close to "affiliate" in .htaccess which means there are no rules hijacking this one. I'm totally stumped. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Check your directory and see if there are any other files/directories with the name `affiliate*`

Comment: I can confirm there are not. There's only the one affiliate.php file.

Comment: Can you try a new browser to test it.